# Expiration date of the auto renewing subscription

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

Have a question about expiration date of the subscription. I have following code with works without errors where I validate receipt and where I have a little issue. My expiration date doesn't change. So If I buy subscription again and again my expiration date stay the same and I always fall into else clause because expiration date is "older" than "new" one.

What I do wrong with it?

```
private func complete(transaction: SKPaymentTransaction) {

        let receiptValidator = ReceiptValidator()
        let result = receiptValidator.validateReceipt()

        switch result {
        case let .success(receipt):
            guard let purchase =  receipt.inAppPurchaseReceipts?.filter({ $0.productIdentifier == IAPProducts.autoRenewable.rawValue }).first else {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(transaction.payment.productIdentifier), object: nil)
                return
            }

            if purchase.subscriptionExpirationDate?.compare(Date()) == .orderedDescending {
                print("expirationDate: \(purchase.subscriptionExpirationDate!)")
                print(" now's date: \(Date())")
            // true clause stuff
            } else {

                // false clause stuff
                print("Subscription has ended")
            }

            // other stuff

        case let .error(error):
            print("receipt is invalid")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
```

So the console output like this:

> expirationDate: 2017-11-01 09:08:11 +0000
>   now's date: 2017-11-01
>   10:35:11 +0000

What do I miss?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found out that my sandbox user made too many transactions. So I create another one and now code works as expected.

Comment: I am having same issue, I just copied your function in my IAPManager, it is giving me error ReceiptValidator() ->Use of unresolved identifier ReceiptValidator also paymentQueue.finishTransaction(transaction) -> Value of type (SKPaymentQueue [SKPaymentTransaction]) -> () has no member finishTransaction, would you be able to share how to get rid of these error, much appreciate your help, needless to say I am just a beginner and your help will go a long way